# A/B testing of posts with unique URLs for each variant AND editing in custom fields

Tags: posts, testing, split

I'm wondering if anyone could offer advice on how to think about creating an A/B testing plugin for posts that:

**A) lets me assign unique URLs for each variant post<sup>**1)</sup>** and**

**B) is customizable on the frontend (i.e. new-post.php).**

There seems to be two ways I could go about doing this:

1. The first way: Create three separate posts, use the Shrimptest plugin to test, and exclude two of the posts from single.php (This was basically the answer that [Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26362/creating-unique-post-urls-for-a-b-testing-is-this-even-possible) gave when I asked about it on Stackexchange. The **problem** with this solution, though, is that I would have to go into the files to edit the code every time I want to test a different batch of posts. And I can't figure out a way for it to meet requirement B.)
2. The alternate way: Create custom fields in new-post.php that would give an editor the option to write in alternate headlines and upload different Facebook images and FB text. This is my preferred option right now since everything would be customizable from new-post.php. The **problem** is that I'm not sure how to meet requirement A (a unique URL for each variant I test). Is it even possible to create a custom field in new-post.php that assigns sub-URLs on top of the default URL?

Any tips or suggestions on any part of the problems I described would be great! Thanks in advance!

---

*Note:*
<sup>**1)**</sup> The reason I need requirement A (unique URLs for each variant) is because I ultimately want to measure shareability of my posts on social networks.

*For example:* If I launch a post with Headline A, FB picture B upon sharing, and FB text B upon sharing, I want the number of clicks on that A/B/B variation to be tracked. Thus I need to assign a unique URL to that variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try our free [MaxA/B plugin](http://maxfoundry.com/plugins/maxab). It was made for split testing different URLs.

Comment: Hmm, I remember looking on it but passing because it seemed to work with pages, not posts. Or maybe I should do more research?Thanks!

Comment: What job does your plugin do without the commercial parts?

Comment: Linda - That's correct, the MaxA/B plugin only works with pages, not posts. Sorry, I missed that detail.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation when talking about your own products. Also it is good practice to explain at least in brief **why** something is a fitting solution to original question, rather just throw in a link.

Comment: @DaveDonaldson Do you have any thoughts on how to get started making a plugin like yours work with posts? I mean, theoretically it should be possible, right?

Comment: @Rarst - Sorry, should've made that clearer. I was just tryinbg to be quick, nothing shady intended.

Comment: @Dave Donaldson no worries, just poking you in right direction of what makes good transparent answer on site :)

Comment: @Linda - Yes it's possible. With some minor tweaks MaxA/B could be made to work with posts as well as pages. At the top of the /includes/experiment-new.php file you'll see a call to get_pages(). If you change that to get pages and posts, you'd be on your way.

Comment: @DaveDonadson It works! Except I noticed that when I set the posts as variations 1, 2, etc., all of them continue to appear in my post stream.

Comment: I guess this makes sense... since all the "variant" pages with MaxA/B must all be live as long as you have the URL, right?

Comment: @Linda - That's correct, but with a little more work you can exclude certain posts from the loop. See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-exclude-a-post-from-the-loop.